# How to manually set up localization for google chrome app（language-switcher）

Tags: javascript, internationalization, google-chrome-app

I develop a google chrome app using java-script. i want my app could have a language switcher to switch from English to Chinese. When i look at my app, i realize i am using chrome.18n  where there is a folder called _locales and en/messages.json.  so, i create zh/messages.json under _locales. now the problem is coming. how can the language switcher switch locales from en/messages.json to zh/messages.json?????
my here is my localization.js

```
function localize() {
  var localized = 0;

  var translate = function(messageID) {
    localized++;
    console.log(chrome.i18n.getMessage(messageID));
    return chrome.i18n.getMessage(messageID);
  };

  $('[i18n]:not(.i18n-replaced').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);

    element.html(translate(element.attr('i18n')));
    element.addClass('i18n-replaced');
  });

  $('[i18n_title]:not(.i18n_title-replaced').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);

    element.attr('title', translate(element.attr('i18n_title')));
    element.addClass('i18n_title-replaced');
  });

  $('[i18n_value]:not(.i18n_value-replaced').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);

    element.val(translate(element.attr('i18n_value')));
    element.addClass('i18n_value-replaced');
  });

  $('[i18n_placeholder]:not(.i18n_placeholder-replaced').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);

    element.attr('placeholder', translate(element.attr('i18n_placeholder')));
    element.addClass('i18n_placeholder-replaced');
  });


return localized;
```

Comment: chrome.i18n automatically loads the UI language of the browser configured in its settings. There's no way to specify the language programmatically so if that's what you want, you'll have to reimplement the whole thing, which is not trivial. Maybe there are existing solutions so try googling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to manually tell the program to tell the program to switch between locales. Just makes sure to [internationalize it](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n#details) and app will adjust to the browser:

> Once an extension or app is internationalized, translating it is
>   simple. You copy messages.json, translate it, and put the copy into a
>   new directory under _locales. For example, to support Spanish, just
>   put a translated copy of messages.json under _locales/es. The
>   following figure shows the previous extension with a new Spanish
>   translation.

Comment: No, it does not works. For example, my web browser is Chinese. However, it still run en/message.json, In a word, itself can not distinguish according to web UI

Comment: The app we developing are no longer in google store.. it is a desktop version allow user to use without connection of internet